# React native camera roll not returning any images in getPhotos and getAlbums method in ios

Tags: ios, react-native, camera-roll, react-native-community

I am currently using @react-native-community/cameraroll currently and i am trying to get images and albums on my ios device.
The following is the code I tried

```
                    CameraRoll.getPhotos({})
                        .then((res) => {
                            console.log("result 1", res)
                        }).catch((error) => { })

                    CameraRoll.getAlbums({})
                        .then((res) => {
                            console.log("result 2", res)
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            console.log(error);
                        });
```

result 1 and result 2 give the following result

```
result 1 {"edges": [], "page_info": {"has_next_page": false}}
result 2 []
```

Any help would be appreciated. The same code works well on Android.

Comment: Hi, Have you solved this problem?

Comment: I know the reason.
because only one Recent Photos.
you  can create a custom title album.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with a lot of combinations and the one below worked for the ios device -

```
CameraRoll.getPhotos({ first: 5000, assetType: 'Photos' })
            .then((result) => {
                const tempBuckets = [];
                var edgesArr = result.edges;
            }).catch((error) => { })
```

The result here contains an edges array that has all the images and their respective properties.
The count '5000' is an arbitrary number i have used, without which the result array obtained was empty.

Comment: What about CameraRoll.getAlbums?
How to solve it ?

Comment: @C.Wei I found a way to make it work with getAlbums
[context]
I found the solution on this Issue: https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll/issues/204
There is a PR under review to correct this issue:
https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll/pull/324

Comment: [solution]
You can do this at your own risk (because the PR is still under review, but I managed to use it without any problem to pick user photos)
You need to install this version of @react-native-community/cameraroll https://github.com/Fredi70/react-native-cameraroll (from PR)
You can do this using yarn: ```yarn add @react-native-community/cameraroll@https://github.com/Fredi70/react-native-cameraroll --exact```
Using this package, simple run ```CameraRoll.getAlbums({assetType: "Photos", albumType: "All"})``` and you're good to go :)

Answer (score 1):

the solution is to add permission before request like

```
async function hasAndroidPermission() {
    const permission = 
   PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
  
    const hasPermission = await PermissionsAndroid.check(permission);
    if (hasPermission) {
      return true;
    }
  
    const status = await PermissionsAndroid.request(permission);
    return status === 'granted';
  }
```

and use like this

```
const Gallery = async () =>{
    if (Platform.OS === "android" && !(await hasAndroidPermission())) {
        return;
      }
    CameraRoll.getAlbums({assetType: "Photos", albumType: "All"})
      .then((r:any) => {
        console.log("images-->",r)
      })
      .catch((err:any) => {
         //Error Loading Images
         console.log("err->",err)
      });
   

}
```